# Оптимизировать SQL запрос

Tags: php, mysql, sql

В БД (в 5-ти таблицах одновременно, суммарно примерно 20000 строк) осуществляется живой поиск:

В зависимости от значения radio в форме осуществляется поиск по адресу, имени (полные Ф.И.О.) или телефону:

```
if ($radio == 'by_address') {
    $searchby = 'address';
    $key = '%' . $keywords . '%';
    $orderby = 'ORDER BY `address` ASC';
} elseif ($radio == 'by_name') {
    $searchby = 'name';
    $key = '%' . $keywords . '%';
    $orderby = 'ORDER BY `name` ASC';
} elseif ($radio == 'by_phone') {
    $searchby = 'phones';
    $key = $keywords . '%';
    $orderby = 'ORDER BY `phones` ASC';
} else {
    $searchby = 'address';
    $key = '%' . $keywords . '%';
    $orderby = 'ORDER BY `idnew` ASC';
}
```

сам запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
         id, (id + 100000) as idnew, name, address, phones, district 
    FROM $pack_bp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id, (id + 100000) as idnew, name, address, phones, district 
    FROM $pack_lp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id, (id + 100000) as idnew, name, address, phones, district 
    FROM $pack_rp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id, (id + 100000) as idnew, name, address, phones, district 
    FROM $pack_dp

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        id, (id + 100000) as idnew, name, address, phones, district    
    FROM $pack_cp           
) AS foo

WHERE 
    upper($searchby) LIKE  upper($key)

$orderby

LIMIT 
    0, $limit_results
```

Как оптимизировать запрос? Теперь поиск осуществляется очень долго секунд 20.

add:

- upper - используется для того чтобы ввод в формуму запроса был регистро независимым для удобства.
- 5 таблиц не объеденные в одну т.к. обновляются независимо друг от друга в разное время.

Comment: Первое что просится - вынести WHERE в каждый из подзапросов.

Comment: Я вижу в запросе 5 таблиц, а не баз. А если это таблицы - то почему это не одна таблица с типом записи ? если бы была одна исключили бы кучу юнионов. И видимо надо нормализовать структуру, бить адреса на компоненты, что бы искать те же улицы в справочниках,которые гораздо короче. И надо добиться таких like у которых в начале не стоит '%', а лучше что бы они заменились на четкое равенство

Comment: И в еще надо исключить upper от колонки таблицы. видимо хранить сразу в верхнем регистре.

Comment: Лучше выствить регистро независимый `collation` типа `utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Покажите функцию создания хотя бы для одной таблицы (CREATE TABLE ...). Подозреваю, индексов у вас тоже нет. Так же,  для текстового поиска MySQL всегда медленный. Посмотрите на Elasticsearch , Sphinx search, Solr, Lucene.

Comment: `(id + 100000) as idnew` - Зачем? `ORDER BY idnew ASC` = `ORDER BY id ASC` = Сортировка по умолчанию(если с индексами порядок).

Comment: andr0000 to @Arnial, спасибо за совет, столбцы name, address теперь с collation типа utf8_unicode_ci, было utf8_general_ci. upper соответственно было удалено. Прироста скорости не появилось.

Comment: andr0000 to @E_p, спасибо за совет, (id + 100000) as idnew - удалил, ORDER BY idnew ASC - удалил. Прироста скорости не появилось.

Comment: andr0000 to @Mike, исключил заменой collation типа utf8_general_ci на utf8_unicode_ci. Прироста скорости не появилось.

Comment: @Andrey Я ничего про collation ни слова не говорил, он ни на что не повлияет до тех пор, пока в начале like стоит '%', потому как когда он есть индексы использовать невозможно и они не используются. И невозможно оптимизировать запрос до тех пор пока в нем столько union. Если нужна скорость - то все поля по которым ищем разбиваем на слова или на некие другие единицы и пишем в отдельную поисковую таблицу. хотя конечно для этого существует полнотекстовый поиск он лучше заточен для таких задач

Answer (score 1):

Поиск по всего лишь 20000 строк будет происходить практически мгновенно, если не копировать каждый все эти строки в новую таблицу, как это происходит сейчас.

Поэтому детский лепет про "обновление в разное время" надо забыть, сделать ОДНУ таблицу, и искать по ней.

Чтобы отличать разные источники, добавить в общую таблицу отдельное поле, в которое и писать все эти "лэпэ, рэпе и пэрэ". таким образом запрос

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type='lp'
```

даст искомую таблицу "pack_lp" если вдруг понадобилось получить досуп к данным конкретного источника.

Answer (score 0):

1. Не вижу проблемы объединить таблицы в одну, как писали ранее.
2. Если все оставлять также, ввиду известного параметра $searchby, можно селектить только из нужной таблицы. Например:

   ```
   if $searchby = 'by_adress' begin
     select * from $first_table where $blabla
   end
   else if $searchby = 'by_phone' begin
     select * from $second_table where $blabla
   end
   ```
3. Проверить есть ли индексы, если нет - проставить.
4. В переменные $pack_ХХ только название таблицы? Или там какой то набор таблица с джойнами? Если последнее - напишите какой.
5. Если результат отображается пользователю. наверняка не нужны все записи таблицы, тогда используйте select top X * from
6. Если сделав все, проблема останется - смотрите план запроса.

Comment: andr0000 to @T.Zagidullin, 1) таблицы объединять нельзя т.к. они формируются в разное время и импортируются из разных источников. 2) Таблицы имеют одинаковую структуру, но разное содержание. т.е. во всех таблицах содержатся столбцы id, name, address, phones, district.

Comment: andr0000 to @T.Zagidullin, 5) select top X * from разве это не тоже самое что LIMIT 0, $limit_results, в моем случае $limit_results = 8.